# 504 Gateway Time-out during python requests

Tags: python-3.x

```
test.py

import logging
import requests
import json
import logging
s = requests.Session()


def work_request(response_id):
    print("id: "+str(response_id))
    logging.info("id: "+str(response_id))
    headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer gjhnjkfhsdafkanfjkadnjk"
            }
    post_url = "https://api.animose/devb/io"
    post_json_data = {
        "work": {
            "id": response_id,
            "link": "https://api.animose/",
            "source": "animose"
        }
    }

    post_data = json.dumps(post_json_data)
    print(post_data)
    p = s.post(post_url, data=post_data, headers=headers)
    print(p.text)



test1.py

#! /usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import json
from test import work_request
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
from_address = ""
for key in arguments.keys():
    if key == "from":
        from_address = arguments[key].value

if from_address == "TK-TEST231V3NK":
    response_id = "TK-TEST231V3NK"
    work_request(response_id)

Response receiving: 
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

From cgi arguments I am able to receive from address key and I am passing the key(id) to next script test.py. For 2 days the request post worked correctly after two days its is showing 504 Gateway Time-out. And response which is receiving is have shown above. The network connectivity is perfect. From first script logged id is correct but unable to post. Is there solution to resolve the problem.

Comment: So, what changed between the working and non-working code? I guess it's not on your side, which means the remote part of the question is missing. Have you contacted the people operating the remote system?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt When I contacted them they told they have receiving GET response instead of POST

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Is there any problem I didnt close the requests session?